# AJAX call returning a dynamic list ... loading to ko.observableArray

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, knockout.js

I am trying to call to a Web service which returns a dynamic list. I need the list in JSON and I need to then load it to a `ko.observableArray`. I know the call to the Web service works, but I keep getting errors on the load. Is my syntax okay?

```
function getEm(zip) {
    $.ajax('/Services/TheatreLocationList.asmx/getTheatres', {
        type        : 'POST',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType    : 'json'
    }).done(function(data) {
        self.theatreData = ko.observableArray(data || [ ]);
    });
}
```

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: this is the error The argument passed when initializing an observable array must be an array, or null, or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the value of data *before* passing the argument. I would `console.log(json)` to make sure you're getting back what you expect from your service call.

```
function getEm(zip) {
    $.ajax('/Services/TheatreLocationList.asmx/getTheatres', {
        type        : 'POST',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType    : 'json'
    }).done(function(json) {
        var data = json.length > 0 ? json : [];
        self.theatreData = ko.observableArray(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Brandon, thanks for your assistance ... the error is not longer, but I am not getting anything my data is null. Here is the asmx ... when I used it in my code behind ... it returned the correct list ... do you see anything incorrect:

Comment: Sorry, your link didn't come through. My experience with .NET anymore is very limited, but I'm more than happy to take a look.

Comment: its okay ... you are so nice to help. I have been working with .NET for about 3 years and I still find challenges with it. I new used AJAX before. could it be that I need to be doing a GET instead of a POST?

Comment: I worked in the Microsoft stack from 1996 to 2006, then switched to Python and never looked back :)  With REST style services, GET should retrieve data, POST should create data, PUT/PATCH should modify data, etc, so I would try to keep my methods as close to that as possible. Also make sure you're returning the proper mimetype for what you're requesting from your jQuery ajax call. Based on your method name, I would be using a GET call instead of a POST.

Comment: okay so... if I am going to a webservice to retrieve data ... I should do a GET?

Comment: That is correct. If you're making a request to the same domain, you should be fine simply returning json data with a mimetype of 'application/json'. If your services are running on a different domain, you'll need to be making a jsonp request.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood... so I am to do a GET ... I am making the request to the same domain.

Comment: No worries. If you post a Gist of your asmx, I might be able to spot the problem.

Comment: [WebMethod]        
        public List<dynamic> getTheatres(){List<dynamic> TheatreList = new List<dynamic>();
            int radius = Regal.Core.Helpers.ConfigHelper.GetIntValue("SearchRadius", 30);
            IFrdiTheatreRepository frdiTheatreRepo = FrdiTheatreRepository.CreateBusinessObject();
            TheatreCollection theatreCollection = frdiTheatreRepo.GetAllTheatresFromRegalByPostalCode("60613", radius);
            TheatreList = (theatreCollection.ToList<dynamic>());
            return theatreCollection.ToList<dynamic>();

Comment: So...what's returned is a List of type<T>, not a JSON array. I would think you would need to serialize your objects to JSON before you send them in the response.

Comment: oh okay, let me try that

Comment: well that did not work. but thanks for all of your assistance.

Comment: Hmm. Sorry that didn't work. In a nutshell, what you need to return should be in the format: `[{key: value}, ...]`

Comment: You're welcome. Please let me know what solution you come up with. I'm always interested to see.